# Mongoose Library fetching results tooo slow

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, document, aws-documentdb

I am using mongoose Libray to fetch data using $in query.
It is taking too much time to return the results.

I am using documentDB as my database.. there are 250k documents in my collection and one of the field is indexed.
Whenever i use explain to get the query execution time its giving me around 250 milliseconds. but when i use normal execution its taking around 15 seconds to return the results.(I am doing this using npm's mongoose package).
I have tried everything from lean to parallel processing of $in query in batches.
but its taking the same time always.
(there are around 800+ parameters in the $in query)

**Update:**

Turns out projection of data while fetching reduces the time by 60%.

please suggest more of such optimizations

Comment: you're probably doing something wrong in your *code* if the request for 2.5 of these lakh+documents takes that long (how do you get 0.5 of a document though). 800 parameters in a query also seems excessive

Comment: if the number of parameters is low.. the query becomes faster... also i am storing very large nested data in the document

Comment: `number of parameters is low.. the query becomes faster` so the number of parameters seems to be the issue

Comment: Please use universal measurements instead of local words like *lakh* that the rest of the world does not use or understand

Answer (score 0):

> number of parameters is low.. the query becomes faster

As Jaromanda X says - the number of parameters seems to be the issue

Consider how you can alter the way you store your data.  You give no details of what is the 800 parameters nor how many documents.  I am going to guess the parameters are words.

You could consider storing the words as tokens (with integer identifiers) and then store the tokens in an additional array in each document.  This would take less space and search an array of integers may be faster.

Next you need to consider using different storage / indexing technology.  Consider a search engine like SOLR or Elastic Search.  They are built to handle what seems to be your use case.